# Как в Python из ключа json сделать заголовок csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, csv

Есть данные формата json, структура такая -

```
{"q":"1",
"w":[{"qwe": "123","rty":"456","uio":"789"},
     {"qwe": "657","rty":"345","uio":"087"}]}
```

Примерно так он выглядит. При парсинге в общем ключи из json нужно превратить в заголовки в csv. Он должен выглядеть так -

```
qwe,rty,uio
123,456,789
657,345,087
```

**НО**, json может выглядеть так -

```
{"q":"1",
"w":[{"qwe": "123","rty":"456","uio":"789"},
     {"qwe": "657","rty":"345","uio":"087"},
     {"tert": "er54t", "uetn": "er54t", "ywfe": "er54t", "kjgn": "er54t", "azvd": "er54t"]}
```

А в csv он выглядит так -

```
qwe,rty,uio
123,456,789
657,345,087
er54t,er54t,er54t,er54t,er54t
```

В конце концов его надо превратить в такое -

```
qwe,rty,uio
123,456,789
657,345,087
tert,uetn,ywfe,kjgn,azvd
er54t,er54t,er54t,er54t,er54t
```

Мб есть возможность как-то переопределить ключи в заголовки заранее и в соответствии с ключами создавать строку с заголовками при каждом изменении кол-ва ключей. Данные не могу скинуть. Можно и логику просто описать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать из ваших данных словарь, в котором ключами будут заголовки, а значениями списки строк. Например так:

```
{
    ('qwe', 'rty', 'uio'): [
        [123, 456, 789],
        [657, 345, 087]
    ],
    ('tert', 'uetn', 'ywfe', 'kjgn', 'azvd'): [
        ['er54t', 'er54t', 'er54t', 'er54t', 'er54t']
    ]
}
```

Таким образом мы сгруппируем строки с одинаковыми заголовками и с такой структурой работать будет чуть удобнее.

Используем [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), значениями по умолчанию в котором указываем списки, чтобы было проще добавлять туда данные.

```
In [31]: import csv                                                        

In [32]: import collections                                                

In [33]: result = collections.defaultdict(list)                            

In [34]: data                                                              
Out[34]: 
{'q': '1',
 'w': [{'qwe': '123', 'rty': '456', 'uio': '789'},
  {'qwe': '657', 'rty': '345', 'uio': '087'},
  {'tert': 'er54t',
   'uetn': 'er54t',
   'ywfe': 'er54t',
   'kjgn': 'er54t',
   'azvd': 'er54t'}]}
```

Заполняем словарь

```
In [35]: for d in data['w']: 
    ...:     result[tuple(d.keys())].append(d.values()) 
    ...:                                                                   

In [36]: result                                                            
Out[36]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {('qwe', 'rty', 'uio'): [dict_values(['123', '456', '789']),
              dict_values(['657', '345', '087'])],
             ('tert',
              'uetn',
              'ywfe',
              'kjgn',
              'azvd'): [dict_values(['er54t', 'er54t', 'er54t', 'er54t', 'er54t'])]})
```

Записываем результат в файл:

```
In [37]: with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf=8') as f: 
    ...:     writer = csv.writer(f) 
    ...:     for k, v in result.items(): 
    ...:         writer.writerow(k) 
    ...:         for i in v: 
    ...:             writer.writerow(i)
```

Наверное лучше было бы записывать в несколько разных файлов, потому что так считывать будет удобнее, чем когда все записано в файл с разными заголовками.